# Async Override OnAuthorization in AuthorizeAttribute MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, authorization

I am using MVC 5.0 I am adding a Authorization Attribute.

I am overriding the ONAuthorization method and inside there i am calling a async method.

```
 public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      var isValid = await validationClass.IsAnonymousUserValid();
      if (!isValid)
      {
        throw new AuthException();
      }
    }
}
```

When i run this code i get the following error 
**"InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."**

Any ideas on how to get around this?

This is not a duplicate of the MVC4 question as we were promised by microsooft that it would work in the future. It worked in Web APi by using the AuthorizationFilterAttribute.

Comment: How is this method being called? `async void` methods should be avoided unless they can't be (e.g. event handlers).

Comment: IT is an attribute on a controller

Comment: Its not a duplicate this did not work in mvc4

Comment: But we were told it would work in the next releases...

Comment: @Jeepers You can't use async/await in MVC 5 filters either. That functionality is coming in MVC 6, which is part of ASP.NET 5, as explained in the link stuartd provided.